# Remove .js file works but a warning persist

Tags: drupal, themes, overriding

i would like to remove a .js file from a drupal module to override this .js one in my theme.

So, in my `MYTHEME_preprocess_page()` function I added the following code:

```
  //Delete logintoboggan.js and replace by our own in .info file

  $tmpJs = drupal_add_js();

  if (isset($tmpJs['module']['sites/all/modules/logintoboggan/logintoboggan.js'])) unset($tmpJs['module']['sites/all/modules/logintoboggan/logintoboggan.js']);  

  $vars['scripts'] = drupal_get_js($tmpJs);
```

This for, but a warning message appear on the website:

> warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in /home/mykitxen/public_html/example.com/includes/common.inc on line 2210.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the first parameter of [`drupal_get_js()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_get_js/6) ($scope), which should be `'header'` or `NULL` in your case (with NULL just triggering the default `'header'`). So the last line of your code should be:

```
$vars['scripts'] = drupal_get_js('header', $tmpJs);
```

or

```
$vars['scripts'] = drupal_get_js(NULL, $tmpJs);
```

---

NOTE: This assumes Drupal 6. If you are using Drupal 7, you might want to take a look at [`hook_js_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_js_alter/7).

Comment: Thanks for the NOTE for Drupal 7 you will want to look at hook_js_alter().